# How can I filter a Django-Model with 2 foreign keys?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following models:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(EventType)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)

class Order(models.Model):
    requester = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    email = models. EmailField()
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    payment_date = models.DateTimeField()
    added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    viewed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=6,blank=True,null=True)

class Picture(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media')
    show_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null= True)
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    picture = models.ForeignKey(Picture)
    amount = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

I'm trying to count all the Orders that belong to each event. Sometimes, there are orders that are in many events, that's why I can't use a FK between Order and Event.

I've tried to get all the "OrderItem", then go up to Picture, and then go up to Event, so if there is a picture in an order that belong to an event, the counter counts one. But this is where I get stuck.

This is a part of my view.py:

```
active_events = Event.objects.filter(is_active=True)
pictures_detail = OrderItem.objects.all()
picture = Picture.objects.all()
print_order = PrintOrder.objects.all()
context_dict['print_order'] = {}

for event in active_events:
    print_order_counter = 0
    for detail in pictures_detail:
        for pic in picture:
            for order in print_order:
                print_order_counter += 1
                for orders in pictures_detail:
                    context_dict['print_order'].update(
                        {event.id : print_order_counter})
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Without spelling out a complete picture, it seems you're using a complicated scheme. Using the `related_name` keyword argument for a model's field definition allows you to find all reverse-related foreign key objects; this can be set per foreign key and called by a parent model.

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
    picture = models.ForeignKey(Picture,related_name='order_items')
    amount = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

for pic in Picture.objects.all():
    print(pic.order_items.all())

>>> [queryset of all order_items related to first Picture instance in Picture.objects.all()]
>>> [queryset of all order_items related to second Picture instance... etc.]
```

Comment: sorry, but this is very bad practice and should not be used under any circumstances. You should call Picture.objects.all().prefetch_related('order_items') which will make just 2 queries no matter how many items you have in database. If he had milion pictures in database, django would run milion queries without it.

Comment: That's true, in addition to using related_name there's a lot more to learn regarding db performance. I strictly wanted to introduce related_name to the user.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is not correct. You will kill your database that way. If you would need more info than just count, then you should use `prefetch_related`, otherwise when looping it will hit database in every iteration.

If you need multiple orders for multiple events, then there is many-to-many relationship https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Since you just need count Orders for Event, it's even easier.
Let's name each foreign key in the way with unique `related_name`:

```
class Picture(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, related_name='event_pictures')

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='ordered_items')
    picture = models.ForeignKey(Picture, related_name='picture_orders')
```

Now, It's a bit hard for me to navigate in the database on the spot, but you should be able to do something like:

```
Events.objects.annotate(Count('event_pictures__picture_orders__order'))
```

Maybe a modify will be needed or adding a distinct. However you should definitely use this approach and not any iteration in python. That would completely kill the app. However if you would absolutely need to, then definitely use `prefetch_related('event_pictures__picture_orders__order')`, as mentioned earlier.

Comment: What is that that you call "Count"? If I try that, it says "global name 'Count' is not defined" Is it just an empty variable?

Comment: @RogerGonzalez it is django function, to use it, you have to import it `from django.db.models import Count` more info in docs where you can find all the functions on aggregating https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate